# Automating query selection based on combo box on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Okay, friends, I'm leaving my job in a week and a half, and I'm trying to make what I've done easier for my boss to do. He has no access knowledge, so I'm trying to create a form that will automate the reports I've been generating. Rather than create a different form for all the different reports, I'm trying to automate it from a table of parameters. Here's what I'm going for:
I have a table, which I have created, which is comprised of 5 fields. I'd like to use these fields to fill parameter fields in a standard form template. The five fields in my table are as follows:

1. The type of query being run (the result spit out)
2. The queries that generate this report, separated by a comma and no space. `"QRYNAMEA,QRYNAMEB"`
3. The Table which these queries generate, which will be used by `transferspreadsheet`
4. The destination excel file, which already has a pivot table set up to feed of the data.
5. The input sheet of this excel file. Currently, all of these sheets are called "Input". (that isn't important)

My issue comes with having no idea where to go after I've made my combo box. I know enough visual basic to automate my queries, but not enough to populate the form with the information in 3,4 and 5 (so far, I've been manually changing these for different queries). I have no idea how to look up the record in the table from the choice in the 'choosebox', and then select individual fields from that in my automation.

I'm pretty confident in my ability to parse #2 and automate the queries, and to put the values into the fields I'm looking at, but I don't know how to actually pull those values from the table, before I can do these things. I also can't seem to describe this well enough for google to help me.

Has anyone done something like this before? I'm assuming I just lack knowledge of one of the VBA libraries, but I've not had any luck finding out which.

edit:
my inclination at this point is to create a query for this table, which will return a single field depending on the input I give. I can imagine doing this in SQL, but I still don't know how to populate the forms, nor extract the field object from the table once I get it.

I have to head out for the day, but I'll be back on Friday to keep working on this, and I'll post my solution, once I find it. This seems like a unique conundrum, and it would be nice to give an answer to it.

Final edit: code is polished (does not have much in the way of error handling):

1. The first method, which pulls the fields from the table and populates the form, is activated by choosing a new entry in the combo box and looks like this:

   ```
   Private Sub QuerySelect_Change()
   Dim db As Database
   Dim rec As Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Queries to Run], [Source Table], [Destination Spreadsheet], [Destination Sheet Name] FROM TBL_QRY_SETTINGS WHERE TBL_QRY_SETTINGS.[Query Type] Like '" & [Forms]![QuerySelector]![QuerySelect] & "';")
   [Forms]![QuerySelector]![QueriesToRun].Value = rec("Queries to Run")
   [Forms]![QuerySelector]![SourceTable].Value = rec("Source Table")
   [Forms]![QuerySelector]![FileDest].Value = rec("Destination Spreadsheet")
   [Forms]![QuerySelector]![SheetName].Value = rec("Destination Sheet Name")
   Set rec = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```
2. The second code pulls that data to run the query. I like how this turned out. It runs when a button near the combobox is clicked.

   ```
   Private Sub DynamicQuery_Click()
   Dim qryArray As Variant
   Dim i As Integer

   qryArray = Split([Forms]![QuerySelector]![QueriesToRun], ",")
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
   For i = LBound(qryArray) To UBound(qryArray)
       Debug.Print qryArray(i)
       DoCmd.OpenQuery (qryArray(i))
   Next
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, [Forms]![QuerySelector]![SourceTable], _
       [Forms]![QuerySelector]![FileDest], _
           True, [Forms]![QuerySelector]![SheetName]
   End Sub
   ```

Note that the final code for part (1) is almost the same as the selected answer, except that I am grabbing more than one field. This works because I know that I have unique "Query Types", and my recordset will only contain one record.

Anyway, I hope some people stumble upon this and find it useful. `Send me a message if you do`. As far as I can tell from brief googling, this sort of automation work has not been done in access. It should make it easier for access-illiterate to run their own queries, and be simple for designers to add to, if they want all their queries available after a few clicks.

Someone could conceivably use this to automate a variety of reports in sequence, by iterating through a table like the one I reference.

Comment: there is no automatic way to pull this. If I follow what you are describing it would requre some sort of documentation table that contained all the details you want to display after the query is selected from the combobox.

Comment: @HansUp I can't embed a photo in the post, and I can't figure a way to format it well, so here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EuTi5bY.png
The top row is the only one fleshed out, but they all follow the same formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be massively misunderstanding what you're doing, but I think it's as easy as creating a new form using the form wizard.  It will let you choose the table that contains the data, and it will let you choose which fields you want to add.

You can later change any of the textboxes to combo boxes which will allow you to limit the choices available to fill in.

Am I understanding that correctly?

EDIT: This will fill a variable (MyRandomField) with the contents of a field in a table

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

set db = CurrentDB
set rec = db.OpenRecordSet("Select SomeField from SomeTable Where Something = 'SomethingElse'")

MyRandomField = rec("SomeFieldName")

set rec = Nothing
set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Not quite, unless the other combo boxes would "autofill" depending on what my first one contains. Is there no way to take the result of a query and feed it into a form? Because right now I'm thinking of querying my table for the fields that match my combo box entry, and then reading those values into the text boxes elsewhere on the form, similar to a default value. My big question is, _how can I assign a value from a table or query to a variable in vba?_ It seems like it should be something straightforward, all things considered.

Comment: @GMoany - Look at my edit above.  This will fill a variable with the contents of a field in a table or query.  That is, assuming the WHERE clause returns only 1 record from the table/query.  Otherwise, you can use a "Do While rec.EOF = False" loop to loop through each record returned.

Comment: That is perfect. I've been diddling around in vba trying to open the table as an excel object, but this is what I actually need. Thank you, sir.

Comment: I've uploaded the final code for my project, which was much more than this problem. I was going to correct you on the use of the `[brackets]` in line 5, but it looks like you fixed that.